# How do I draw non-overlapping edge labels in networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, springlayout

How do I draw non-overlapping edge labels in networkx? Using the option `scale` looks better but the edge labels are still overlapping, for instance,

[image]

The related source codes are below:

```
# build a graph
G.add_edge(u, v, r=value)

# plot the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=3)

nx.draw(G, pos)

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'r')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edge_labels)

plt.savefig(filename)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) for spring_layout.  One of the parameters is `k`.

> `k` (float (default=None)) – Optimal distance between nodes. If None the distance is set to 1/sqrt(n) where n is the number of nodes. Increase this value to move nodes farther apart.

So call `spring_layout` with `k=5/math.sqrt(G.order())` or something other value that will increase the distance.

Comment: thx. it is not scalable (it looks worse for big graphs). It might be a good solution to use other graph visualization tools, like Graphviz.